# U-Turns not mentioned on instructions steps

Tags: openrouteservice

I’m using openrouteservice.org for getting routes/directions in my app. Sometimes, a u-turn is necessary in order to get where you’re going.

I can successfully get the route and the step-instructions, but for some reason, whenever there’s a u-turn involved on the route, it’s not mentioned on the steps/instructions, even if the u-turn is properly drawn.

These are the parameters I’m sending:
{“coordinates”:[[’ + start + ‘],[’ + end + ']],“roundabout_exits”:“true”}

and this is the URL:
https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car

[image]

For the image above, these are the steps I’m getting:

```
“type”:11,“instruction”:“Head southeast on Darby Road”
"type”:6,“instruction”:“Continue straight onto Darby Road”
“type”:10,“instruction”:“Arrive at Darby Road, on the right”
```

If I'd follow this instructions, I'd get lost. There should be a **make a u-turn** instruction after the 1st step.

Here are the coordinates I'm using in case you want to try it yourself, however, this happens anywhere where a U-Turn is involved:

[[-75.30765367967103,39.984496906875016],[-75.30538989528604,39.98212110323286]]

Am I missing some parameter in order to get these missing instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered me on a different forum and it seems it's a bug from openrouteservice.org and it's already reported. It's still not fixed though